# Is there a Hive 2 standalone metastore solution?

Tags: hive, presto, trino

Hive 3 has a standalone metastore which seems to work great... although in order to run the `schematool` I still had to download (but not run) Hadoop.

Unfortunately Presto only works with Hive 1.x and Hive 2.x, as Hive 3 has default ACID2 tables which Presto does not work with (https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/576).

So, I'm trying to understand if I can run the Hive 2.x metastore without the rest of hive (hive server) or Hadoop running.  Like... If I install Hadoop and hive but only run the metastore will it be functional, or are there limitations?

Comment: If you're on AWS, you can single-node EMR as Metastore or use AWS Glue. What's your environment?

Comment: AWS but was trying to do it in a cloud agnostic manner if possible :).  Will look into this though, thanks!

Comment: You can try out Qubole. It supports common Hive metastore (cloud agnostic) for all the major SQL engines Spark-SQL, Hive and Presto. It also supports Hive-3 now with ACID feature